# array merge two arrays with different number of items where there is a matching productid

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am trying to merge two arrays that I have in order to end up with one array. Here is an example of my first array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name1
            [price] => 237.00
            [colour] => Blue
            [image] => http:.............
            [url] => http:.............
            [productid] => 7740792
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name2
            [price] => 87.00
            [colour] => Mauve
            [image] => http://.......
            [url] => http://.......
            [productid] => 7638070
        )
```

Here is an example from my second array:

```
Array
(
    [productId] => 7740792
    [productCode] => 1019534
    [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740915
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740906
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740916
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740923
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740934
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740922
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740933
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7740942
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [productId] => 7638070
    [productCode] => 1004120
    [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638099
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638121
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638117
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638126
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638131
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638092
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638135
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638091
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

what I want to do is end up with an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name1
            [price] => 237.00
            [colour] => Blue
            [image] => http:.............
            [url] => http:.............
            [productid] => 7740792

            [productId] => 7740792 
            [productCode] => 1004120
                  [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638099
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638121
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638117
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638126
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638131
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638092
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638135
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [VariantID] => 7638091
                    [isInStock] => 1
                )
```

I hope this makes sense. I have tried array combine but that wouldn't work as there are different number of items in the arrays. I am learning PHP so sorry if this has already been answered but I haven't been able to apply other code from answers to my case.

Comment: You forgot `name2` and it's variants in the result - guessing by mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($second_array as $k => $v){
    $key = array_search($v['productId'], array_column($first_array, 'productid'));
    if($key !==false){
         $newArray[$k] = array_merge($second_array[$k], $first_array[$key]);
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: I have just noticed that this code works but now I have more than two items  on my second array being ("isInStock") (variantId) (size) but the code only allows me to merge two items. It deletes the (size) key. any help?

Comment: @adamp, I think there is no issue if you have third key i.e. size, please check this - https://3v4l.org/f8Ldg -working fine

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage to get the product id to be the keys of the variant array it's fast and easy:

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= count($names); $j++) {
    if (array_key_exists($names[$j]['productId'],$variants) {
      $names[$j][variants] = $variants[$names[$j]['productId']]['variants'];
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you leave it as is you have to search, which sucks:

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= count($names); $j++) {
   for ($i = 0; $i <= count($variants); $i++) {
      if ($names[$j]['prodcutId'] == $variants[i]['productId']) {
        $names[$j]['variants'] = $variants[$i]['variants'];
        break;
      }        
   }
}
```